# getting a random value of object property and storing to variable

Tags: javascript, object, random

I am trying to get a random value from the object property by comparing properties to the value I get from list item by .text(). I try to store the result to a span after that.

I am trying to find first property of either tv or animals (or any other if added in the future) and then property of either easy, medium or hard

Not sure if the function displayWord is correct or maybe I am missing something else.

Here is some other relevant parts of the code to see what variables referring to. https://jsfiddle.net/peliudzemas/0fqbgo9k/1/

```js
let result = "";
let charadesList = {
  tv : {
    easy : ['Harry Potter', 'James Bond', 'transformers'],
    medium : ['the planet of The Apes', 'Inception', 'finding nemo'],
    hard : ['taken', 'alladin', 'cast away', 'schindler\'s list']
          },

  animals : {
    easy : ['chicken', 'mouse', 'dog'],
    medium : ['lion', 'elephant', 'giraffe'],
    hard : ['monkey', 'panda', 'mole']
  }
}

function displayWord(obj, value1, value2) {
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.p == value1) {
      for (var pp in obj.p) {
        if (obj.p.pp == value2) {
          result += obj.p.pp[Math.floor(Math.random()*obj.p.pp.length)];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $('#word').append(result);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   displayWord(charadesList, selectCategory, selectLevel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but if you know what props you looking for use - in the above example you know - this:

```
function getRandomWord(obj,val1,val2) {
    try {
        return obj[val1][val2][Math.floor(Math.random() * obj[val1][val2].length)];
    } catch {
        return null;
    }
}

function {
    let randomWord = getRandomWord(...params)
    if (randomWord)
        $('#word').append(result);
}
```